# "help your next ones" instead of "help your neighbours"

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm thinking of using the phrase **'help your next one'** instead of **'help your neighbour'**. On Google.com there are only 8 hits - but all of them on 'native English' websites.

Is the proposed phrase acceptable and, more importantly, intrinsically intelligible - yes or no?

Alternatively, should I better use **'help those next to you'** or **'help those who are next to you'**...but to me the connotational idea of nepotism etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Help your *next one*" (or *ones*) is grammatical but doesn't really make sense to this US English speaker.  "Next one" doesn't really mean "neighbor", and if I read the sentence somewhere, I would say, "Help my next *what*?" because *one* has to refer to something.

The examples you've found that use the phrase almost all use it in a context where another phrase gives it meaning, like

> You couldn't help your last client, but maybe you can help your next one.

In this example, *one* is clearly referring to "client".